# Preventing blank fields being accepted

Tags: php

I am trying to fix an error in my code where blank fields would be accepted and allow access to the a1user.php page. So I added what I thought was a way to validate it, to check that neither of the variables storing the input from the fields was blank. When testing, I submitted the blank fields and the page took ages to load and eventually threw up the alert box. But then I got a warning on my page and continuously spammed an error and the alert box. I think I created a loop by mistake but I don't know how else to do it because this obviously didn't work ! :(

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   $Username1 = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["user"]));
   $Password1 = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["pwd"]));

   $file = fopen("user_accounts.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file");

   while(!feof($file))
   {
      $Username2 = trim(fgets($file));
      $Password2 = trim(fgets($file));

      if($Username1 == "" || $Password1 == ""){
         echo '<script language="javascript">';
         echo 'alert("Error - fields blank: Please enter username and password")';
         echo '</script>';
      }
      else
      {
         if($Username1==$Username2 and $Password1 == $Password2)
         {
            header('Location: a1user.php');
         }
         else
         {
            if($Username1=="admin@SNC" and $Password1=="pass1234")
            {
               header('Location: a1admin.php');
            }
         }
      }
      fclose($file);
   }
}
?>
```

UPDATE: Btw this is for a college assignment. I know its insecure, but Im still learning the basics.

My form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why use a While loop? why not if Username and Password => Blank then go to a special page else if the Username and Password => Admin then go to admin panel

Comment: Don't store plain text passwords! And why the heck  htmlspecialchars($_POST["pwd"])?

Comment: You may want to store the `user_accounts.txt` file outside of the document root directory, otherwise anyone could simply request that file to get the credentials.

Comment: I was told to use a while loop by my tutor to check that the input in the field is equal to the log in details stored in the .txt file. I need blank fields to throw up the error, not go to a special page.

Comment: I know its insecure but it is what my tutor has asked me to do for the assignment. Im still learning. It won't be used on a proper website, purely for educational purposes. I am trying to learn and understand the basics and do what has been asked by my tutor. I do understand it is insecure, Im sure added security will be part of a later assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your code like this.

1st change: I moved the test for `$username1==''` and `$password1==''` out of the while loop, not to repeat the test and the alert for each line in your code.

2rd change: I moved this: `fclose($file);` outside of the while loop, you were closing your file handle the first time you enter into the while loop, causing an infinite loop.

3th change: added `die()` after `header` function to tell php to stop executing if there is still any code after the header function

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   $Username1 = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["user"]));
   $Password1 = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["pwd"]));
   if($Username1 == "" || $Password1 == ""){
     echo '<script language="javascript">';
     echo 'alert("Error - fields blank: Please enter username and password")';
     echo '</script>';
  }
  else {

      $file = fopen("user_accounts.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file");

      while(!feof($file))
      {
      $Username2 = trim(fgets($file));
      $Password2 = trim(fgets($file));

         if($Username1==$Username2 and $Password1 == $Password2)
         {
            header('Location: a1user.php');
            die();
         }
         else
         {
            if($Username1=="admin@SNC" and $Password1=="pass1234")
            {
               header('Location: a1admin.php');
               die();
            }
         }
     }
     fclose($file);
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it throws up an error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 40
Which is where it says:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
I don't understand this?

Comment: @charlotterose23 close php, put `?>` after `fclose($file); }` updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, I had just noticed this too. It is half working atm, when I submit blank fields the page refreshes but it is just white, nothing else loads. The alert box does not show either.

Comment: @charlotterose23 updated my answer, removed the `window.location` thing and the `die()` after it, they are not needed as the form is on the same page...